# Hi, I'm trying to figure out the following regex for a sed command

Tags: regex, linux, sed

```
sed "s/\([0-9]\)-\([0-9]\)/\1\2/g" file
```

Can someone break it down and explain what it will do when run.

Thanks.

Comment: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Thanks, But I've already looked through numerous guides. I just can't get my head around this expression.

Comment: [Take a look](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28[0-9]%29-%28[0-9]%29\1\2).

Comment: That regex is incredibly simple (it only uses two operators: parentheses for grouping, and square brackets for character matching). Can't you say which part of it is confusing you? Are you confused because `sed` requires you to escape the parentheses that are used for grouping, while most other regular expression engines don't? That's because `sed` uses Basic Regular Expressions by default, where only some of the simplest operators can be used without escaping.

Comment: If you ask a better question, we can give a better answer that clears up your confusion. If we don't know what you don't understand about it, it's harder for us to address it.

Comment: yeah. What do you mean by escaping the parantheses.

I don't understand what it will substitute and whether it will replace the number with another number or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sed command removes a hyphen(`ie -`) in between two numbers.

Suppose the contents of the `file` are

```
10-2
20-20
9-13
```

Doing  `sed "s/\([0-9]\)-\([0-9]\)/\1\2/g" file` will give you

```
102
2020
913
```

Deciphering the regex :

`[]` - used for a range
`\(..\)` - used for grouping so that you can use \1 for first match \2 for second and so on.

Comment: Thankyou very much! That was the breakdown I was after.